# Spring - one-to-many in Northwind MySQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, northwind

I would like to implement relationship one-to-many between Orders and Customers like in schema given below: [image]

In my datebase I implemented the same schema.  I would like to set OneToMany relationship and finally respond on /{customerID} GET with JSON like this:

```
customerID: "test",
companyName: "testCompany",
...
...
orders: [ 
        { orderID: 123,
           ...//other keys for orderObj
           ...
}]
```

But I have no idea how to achieve that. I tried that way:

```
// ORDER CLASS
@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Integer orderID;
    private String customerID;
    private Integer employeeID;
    private String orderDate;
    private String requiredDate;
    private String shippedDate;
    private Integer shipVia;
    private Float freight;
    private String shipName;
    private String shipAddress;
    private String shipCity;
    private String shipRegion;
    private String shipPostalCode;
    private String shipCountry;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Customer customer;
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return  this.customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer){
        this.customer=customer;
    }
```

And my Customer class:

```
// CUSTOMER
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Customer  {

    @Id
    private String customerID;
    private String companyName;
    private String contactName;
    private String contactTitle;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String region;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
    private String phone;
    private String fax;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerID")
    private Set<Order> orders;
    public Set<Order> getOrders(){
        return orders;
    }
    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
```

Then in my controller:

```
//reads one customer
@GetMapping(value = "/{customerId}")
public  Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable String customerId) {
    return customerRepository.findById(customerId).get();
}
```

The thing is that is not working. Could you please give me any advice?

Comment: try change `mappedBy = "customerID"` to `mappedBy = "customer"`.
you need to specify *owning side* in this attribute, not the foreign key name.

Comment: ```@GetMapping(value = "/{customerId}")
    public  Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable String customerId) {
     return customerRepository.findById(customerId).get();
    }```

That endpoint gives me : Expected ':' instead of 't'

Comment: add `@JsonIgnore` to `Customer customer` field declaration in the `Order` class

Comment: Yeah it is working, but how can I specify the payload? For example for each order I don't need customerID now, because it will be the same for given customer

Comment: you can move from bi-directional to uni-directional association if you don't want to manipulate on `Customer` via `Order`: just remove `Customer` field with the whole hibernate mappings out of `Order` class

Comment: Ok get it. But please explain me how can I decide on which parameters in JSON response will be shown?

Comment: that is configured by jackson (spring uses this lib by default) annotations (one of them is `@JsonIgnore` mentioned above which stops infinite recursion for your case where orders have customer and customer has orders and ...).